# Chrome headless puppeteer: make screenshot render scrollbar

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

It appears when taking a screenshot of a webpage using chrome headless puppeteer, scrollbars are never rendered.

To replicate:

1. Go to their official demo page: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/
2. Change the page.goto('https://example.com') to 'https://backbonejs.org/'.
3. Take a screenshot
4. The scrollbar in the navagation menu (on the left) is not rendered.

Is there a way to turn it on?

Comment: Did it yield same result on your computer/server?

Answer (score 8):

I came across the same problem: our CI, with the headless mode on, wasn't rendering the scrollbar *anymore* for some reason. After some digging, I found out about the following issue on puppeteer's Github repository.

[Headless mode should not force `--hide-scrollbars`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4747)

The quick solution to ensure that scrollbars were rendered, both on our CI with headless and locally, was to explicitly ignore the `--hide-scrollbars` parameter in puppeteer's launch configuration:

```js
this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  // Existing config goes here...
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--hide-scrollbars"]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the site itself toggle scrollbars on/out according to the viewport and some other factors. If you emulate some devices via DevTools you can see the scrollbars disappear. Also, they are present in a headful puppeteer mode.